# Как вынести часть активити за пределы экрана и оперировать ей?

Tags: android, activity

Идея такая. Пользователь сдвигает активити пальцем вниз, после чего, становится виден скрытый за пределами экрана элемент и следует обработка события. Полагаю, будет правильным думать в сторону увеличения высоты активити больше 160dp и установки верхней точки отображения не с 0dp, а с той позиции, которая нам нужна.

На рисунке ниже всё схематично нарисовано. Тёмно-серым обозначена видимая часть экрана, активити обозначена малиновым. Изначально мы видим только часть активити и можем её двигать пальцем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как воплотить эту идею в жизнь?

UPD. Решил попробовать решить задачу через `ScrollView`. Взял пример из интернета. В примере существуют 3 кнопки, нажимаешь последнюю — контент съезжает на 200 пикселей.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 12.05.17.
 */

public class ScrollViewDemoActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonScrollUp, buttonScrollDown, buttonScrollToTop;
    ScrollView myScroll;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sc2);

        buttonScrollUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scrollup);
        buttonScrollDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scrolldown);
        buttonScrollToTop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scrolltotop);
        myScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        myScroll.scrollTo(0, 200);

        buttonScrollUp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myScroll.scrollBy(0, 20);
            }
        });

        buttonScrollDown.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myScroll.scrollBy(0, 20);
            }
        });

        buttonScrollToTop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myScroll.scrollTo(0, 200);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Строчка `myScroll.scrollTo(0, 200);` смещает контент вниз на 200. Я добавляю её сразу после инициализации:

```
myScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
myScroll.scrollTo(0, 200);
```

Не работает!

UPD. Сработало с оборачиванием в Runnable:

```
myScroll.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                myScroll.scrollBy(0, 200);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Возможно это Вам подойдёт: [Овладение Coordinator Layout](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/)

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на то. Поизучаю.

Comment: Не совсем то, что я хотел. Хотелось именно вынести активити за пределы экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместить весь контент в ScrollView, а затем при создании активити сдвинуть позицию скролла

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
sv.scrollTo(..., ...);
```

Comment: ScrollView добавляет справа полосу прокрутки, без неё бы.

Comment: Странно, не работает... Взял у Климова пример, при нажатии последней кнопки работает, если поместить строчку сразу после инициализации, не работает. Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: В onCreate это не работает, верно. 
Нужно такую операцию делать, например, с небольшой паузой. 

Например, sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sv.scrollTo(..., ...);
                    }
                }, 100); 


Чтобы не видеть моргания можно сделать сперва весь контент невидимым и только после скрола делать его видимым

Comment: сработало вот что: myScroll.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                myScroll.scrollBy(0, 200);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ScrollView c атрибутом `android:scrollbars="none"`.